# Limitar numero de insert (Registros)

Tags: php, mysql

Hola a todos estoy realizando un formulario de registro y ya todo esta funcionando perfecto y me hace el insert, lo que no me resulta es que deseo que solo existan dos oportunidades de registro por usuario. En pocas palabras si un usuario ya realizo sus dos registros este no puede utilizar mas el formulario y necesito que salga un alert diciendo que ya agoto sus oportunidades de registro

```
$query = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM tabla1 WHERE valor1 = 
        '$valor1'");

        $result = mysqli_fetch_array($query);
       if ($result == 2) {
               echo'<script type="text/javascript">
                alert("Ya alcanzo su limite de registros");
                window.location.href="home.php";
                </script>';

             }
             
           else ($result > 0) {
               echo'<script type="text/javascript">
                alert("el registro ya fue creado anteriormente");
                window.location.href="home.php";
                </script>';

             }else{

                  $query_insert = mysqli_query($conn, "INSERT INTO 
                    tabla1(valor1,valor2,valor3,valor4,valor5,valor6,valor7) VALUES

                    ('$valor1','$valor2','$valor3','$valor4','$valor5',
                    '$valor6','$valor7')");


                  if ($query_insert) {
                       echo'<script type="text/javascript">
                            alert("el registro ha sido registrada con exito");
                            window.location.href="home.php";
                            </script>';
                  }else{
                         echo'<script type="text/javascript">
                            alert("El registro no ser guardado con exito");
                            window.location.href="home.php";
                            </script>';
                  }
```

Comment: Hola,  ¿has intentado algo para intentar solucionar el problema que tienes? Eso sería de ayuda para orientarte un poco mejor

Comment: @FernandoTorres Lo unico que he intentado es lo que se ve aqui $result == 2, la verdad estoy  un poco perdido

Answer (score 0):

He visto esto y no cuadra

```
 $result = mysqli_fetch_array($query);
       if ($result == 2) {
```

La función mysqli_fetch_array() devuelve un array con una fila del resultado o null si no quedan filas y como parámetro va a llevar al menos el resultado de un una operación de query, no una cadena query.
Si quieres leer el número de registros que devuelve el select puedes usar la función affected_rows

```
$conn = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $pass, $baseDatos);
mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM tabla1 WHERE valor1 = '$valor1'");
$result = mysqli_affected_rows($conn)
```

En $result tienes el número de registros devueltos por select.